# Thread Program on Linux (Posix Thread)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix-api

I want to modify the multithread program on the Linux operating system using this Pthread API.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sum;
void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid
        pthread_attr_t attr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >=0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}

void *runner(void *param);
{
    int i, upper = atoi(param);
    sum = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++)
        sum += i;

    pthread exit(0);
}
```

I want to change that program into a program that has **2 threads that work together to add a number**. But i don't know how to change it, Thanks again for any help that can be offered. I am sorry,because I'm not good at explaining.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first there is 3 errors : the `pthread tid` declaration has no ";", then there is one at the end of your `runner()*` function declaration, and last but not least, a underscore is missing on the last line `pthread_exit(0)`
beware ahah

ok for vars :

```
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_t tid2;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_t attr2;
```

and  in the code after the ifs, add this :

```
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
pthread_create(&tid2, &attr2, runner, argv[2]); // not sure for argv[2]?
```

not sure for argv[2], it depends if it's 2 different numbers?

pthread_join are  no use, they are here only for pausing threads, i think that if you want them to work in parallel, you need to only do "pthread_create" and they should work in parallel (but was i saw on my CS class on parallel programming 3 years ago, it will never be "real real" parallel because only the OS can control this and you need to be some kind of a super root to be able to really control the threads

I mean
it won't be faster because it will not be real parallel prog

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and helping me, but after i compile it the ouput of the program is usage: a.out <integer value> , i still dont understand

Comment: you need to do ./a.out 4  or for example ./a.out 3      I mean just write a number in parameter

Comment: don't forget to select the answer as "good answer for your question" please ahah

Comment: Hai, when i try this ./a 4 the output is sum=0 . Is there something wrong? or indeed it's the output.

Comment: Update: when I enter a number like 30 40 50 the output is no longer 0 but the number below 30 is always sum=0 and there is a Segmentation fault (core dumped) written. I don't know why..

Comment: ah yes it's because it is sensed to take 1 input but i don't know what the program is sensed to do, it depends ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but a really quick and dirty solution based on the existing code is below. I'm assuming you just want two thread to sum a single variable to the input.

An explanation of what's going on: I had to fix some minor syntax issues you have in your code, one big one being the semicolon at the end of the runner function definition. I added a mutex to define a critical section in the runner's for loop. It makes sure only 1 thread can update the sum. I'm assuming you want the sum to equal the input, so we just increment it by 1 and check before incrementing whether the value is still below. Like I said, it's quite quick and dirty, not really the ideal solution. To create two threads, we just call the thread create function twice in main.

See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes for more important about mutexes and the pthread library.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum = 0; // set it once globally
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >=0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&tid1, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
    pthread_create(&tid2, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}

void *runner(void *param) {
    int i, upper = atoi(param);
    // sum = 0;

    int t = pthread_self();

    for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        if (sum < upper) {
            printf("%d incrementing\n", t);
            sum += 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Compile with `cc -o main main.c -pthread`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and helping me, but after i compile it the ouput of the program is 
usage: a.out <integer value> , i still dont understand

Comment: @Chenz Are you providing it with an input when you call the program? I was under the impression given how the code is structured you're expecting an input to be provided, `./program_name 12`

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry I forgot to put the input. i want to ask you something, can the program run without a mutex? when i try without a mutex, the output is sum=0

Comment: if you have multiple threads reading/writing to a variable (single memory location) you will get all kinds of crazy things occurring. If you want consistent results, you have to provide mutual exclusion via some means. Mutexes are one. Otherwise, writing to a single memory location WILL lead to bugs